# Как разобраться с streams в node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, потоки-данных

Пытаюсь разобраться с streams в node.js, прочитал stream-handbook и в голове осталась какая-то каша( Решил пройти stream-adventure и там вот такое задание:

***Надо считать данные с stdin и вывести в stdout в upperCase.***

Я сделал вот так:

```
process.stdin.on('readable', function(){
    var buf = process.stdin.read();
    if(buf){
        process.stdout.write(buf.toString().toUpperCase());
    }
})
```

Но хотелось бы сделать тоже самое через pipe. Я пробовал делать через дополнительный readable стрим, в который пушил уже увеличенные буквы, который связывал уже с stdout. Вот как-то так:

```
var stream = require('stream');
var red = new stream.Readable();


process.stdin.on('readable', function(){
    var buf = process.stdin.read();
    if(buf){
        red.push(buf.toString().toUpperCase());
    }
})


red.pipe(process.stdout);
```

Но выбрасывалась ошибка, которую я даже не знаю как словить(
[image: ошибка]
<sub>(источник: [joxi.ru](http://joxi.ru/a2XYwogslbMRAg.jpg))</sub>

Подскажите пожалуйста как сделать это через pipe без использования дополнительных библиотек.
И был бы очень благодарен за последовательную схему срабатывания событий при поступлении данных в readable stream.

Updated.

Comment: текст ошибки был бы не лишним

Comment: @dizballanze добавил

Answer (score 1):

На основе [документации](https://nodejs.org/api/process.html#process_process_stdin)

```
process.stdin.setEncoding('utf8');

process.stdin.on('readable', function() {
  var chunk = process.stdin.read();
  if (chunk !== null) {
    process.stdout.write(chunk.toUpperCase());
  }
});
```

Версия node.js 0.12.4, никаких установленных модулей, только этот код. Работает.

Comment: Да, я так и сделал. В самом начале вопроса почти точно такой же код) Вот как бы сделать тоже самое, но только через pipe.

Comment: Разница в том, что при указании кодировки ты сразу получаешь строку, а не бинарный буфер. А при чём тут pipe? Он же передаёт поток как есть без модификации, насколько я помню?

Comment: Я видел разницу.
Я думал, что через pipe можно как-то перехватывать поток, модифицировать его и отправлять изменённый. Почти везде для таких фишек используется модуль through и код выглядит примерно так
```js
process.stdin.pipe(through(function(buf, enc, cb){ //code changed buf}).pipe(process.stdout);
```
Насколько я понял, этот модуль работает на основе duplex streams, которые в свою очередь на основе простых readable и writable streams. Вот и хотелось сделать это через pipe) Просто хочется разобраться во всех этих штуках, но толком нигде не нашёл объяснения этих фундаментальных вещей(

Answer (score 0):

вот [тут рекомендуют](https://github.com/google/web-starter-kit/issues/678#issuecomment-101706889) по поводу этой ошибки возвратиться к *node* версии 0.10.

а следующий комментарий рекомендует удалить `npm_modules` а затем выполнить `npm install`, но это, вероятно, не про вашу ситуацию.